# Trying to do a slightly larger than average AXIOS.post to a .NET Web API

Tags: javascript, .net, axios, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to do an AXIOS.post in a Vue.JS application.  It seems that when I get over about 1500 characters the process fails. What I mean by fails it does not even go to the Web API. It goes straight to the error area. This is normally a function that call a .Net Web API that produces a MS Word Document and passes it back to the end user.

```
      let pm = "1234567890,"
```

Create loop to add pm = pm + pm '200 times

```
let updatedData = {        
      memberID: 12345,
      pmids: pm             
  };

  axios({
    method: "post",
    url:         
     "http://localhost:54269/api/DataTable/PostValue",
    params: {
      value: JSON.stringify(updatedData)        
    },  responseType: 'blob' , 
     maxContentLength: Infinity,
     maxBodyLength: Infinity,
     headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',         
      'Accept': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'
 }
  }).then(response =>{ 
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.setAttribute('download', 'DataTable4_.docx');
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
   }) 
  .catch(err => { 
      if( err.response ){
      console.log(err.response.data); 
   }
     if( err.message ){
      console.log("message:  " + err.message); 
   }   
  });
```

} ,

Once PM get over 1500 I get an error

```
 POST http://localhost:54269/api/DataTable/PostValue?value=%7B%22memberID%22:12345,%22pmids%22:%2212345,23456,45678%22%7D 500 (Internal Server Error)
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js?e38e:177
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js?e38e:13
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js?c09c:52
Promise.then (async)
request @ Axios.js?108a:61
wrap @ bind.js?784f:9
saveSwitchValue @ reporterAPI_Unique_PI.vue?5e84:382
create_word_doc_post @ reporterAPI_Unique_PI.vue?5e84:451
toolbarClick @ reporterAPI_Unique_PI.vue?5e84:816
Observer.notify @ observer.js?e8e3:99
Base.trigger @ base.js?3f78:181
GridComponent.trigger @ grid.component.js?9a24:85
Toolbar.toolbarClickHandler @ toolbar.js?3c15:337
Observer.notify @ observer.js?e8e3:99
Base.trigger @ base.js?3f78:181
Toolbar.clickHandler @ toolbar.js?4b00:573
reporterAPI_Unique_PI.vue?5e84:409 
Blob {size: 1151, type: 'application/json'}size: 1151type: "application/json"[[Prototype]]: BlobarrayBuffer: ƒ arrayBuffer()size: (...)slice: ƒ slice()stream: ƒ stream()text: ƒ text()type: (...)constructor: ƒ Blob()Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Blob"get size: ƒ size()get type: ƒ type()[[Prototype]]: Object
```

I should be able to take a fair amount of data and use JSON.stringify and send it to a server, shouldn't I? I'm not talking about uploading Gig of data not even Megs.  If someone knows of some expert training material I'm willing to learn.  I've tried Udemy and YouTube but 99% of all of the Axios posts are small samples.  Or yes-  I have also check my local IIS server and set the Maximum allowed content length to 10737418241073741824

and if you want

<System.Web.Http.HttpPost> <System.Web.Http.Route("api/DataTable/PostValue")>
Public Function PostValue(ByVal value As String) As String 'HttpResponseMessage

String for testing

Comment: If your getting a 500 that means your server side code (or possibly a proxy between your client and server) is failing. Couldn't tell you what without seeing your server side code, but the issue isn't Axios.

Comment: Wait, are you passing this data as a *query parameter*? You have your data in params, not the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is you are trying to pass that big stringified JSON object as a *query parameter*. IIS has a hard cap of 2048 bytes for url length.

Large data objects should be passed as part of a request body, the property your looking for is `data`. Check the Axios docs for more information.

Comment: I agree and it seems that AXIOS is not really designed for more than 2048 bytes.  I have tried everything from params to data- from posts to gets- from json to application/x-www-form-urlencoded to FormData  to everything in between.  If it's not AXIOS it the .NET Web API .  AJAX and jQUery was so much easier for posting data.  Well that's my first mistake.  I assume Posting is sending to server and a Get is pulling.  Might write to file - upload - read - and process.  Not real professional

Comment: What results do you get when you try to post as JSON encoded data. Again Axios is sending your requests just fine, it's your server that has the issues.

Comment: I have a break point right on the name of the controller--  Public Function PostValue(ByVal value As String) As String  and if the updated data is less than 2040 than I can see the values in the string and the break point is hit.  If the data is too large then it does not hit the controller at all and just hit AXIOS error handler with   message:  Request failed with status code 404.   And it sends all of the data in the url string http://localhost:54269/api/DataTable/PostValue?value={"memberID":12345,"pmids":"12345,23456,45678,12345,...........,23456,45678"}

Comment: Ok, but what happens if you send it in *the body* not the url? https://axios-http.com/docs/post_example. If you send the data via the URL param, IIS will fail before it ever gets to your app. Again, the issue is *not with axios*, it's with sending the data as a query param and IIS.

Comment: Sorry for the delay-- I really appreciate your help. The delay was on my part because no matter what I did I got CORS error out of my Local.  Had to deploy an AZURE account and it works great with test code.  I got the string length up over 25K which proves it's working.  Now I need to handle the local CORS problem so I can debug the code easier.  Thanks

Comment: Add some more to length-- now 1,343,447 characters